# How to scroll thumnail images to scroll onclick using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm building a gallery with javascript. I need a function that makes the thumbnail images to scroll onclicking the next button. 
This is whe function I'm creating

```
    clikTag2.onclick = function nextThumb()
    {
        document.getElementById('scrollImg').style.left = '-200px';
        alert('hellos');
        //setTimeout(nextThumb(),5000); 
    }
```

the major problem now is that the alert isn't working even after defining the id of the div

Comment: Try `clikTag2.onclick = function () { ... }` instead

Comment: what is the clickTag2? I mean post your html code.

Comment: make a fiddle please or or post your full code

Comment: Make sure that `clikTag2` is not `null`. Execute `Console.log(clikTag2)`;

Comment: @HTTP this is my cliKTag2:    clikTag2 = document.createElement('a');